# Alpine JS $dispatch-ed properties

Tags: alpine.js

I'm working on a project and curious about Alpine JS $dispatch. I'm wondering if code sample no 1 and no 2 are the same or not? If not how do I write $dispatch 'magic' properties provided by Alpine JS in native Javascript?

Code sample 1 (with Alpine JS)

```js
quill.on('text-change', function () {
  $dispatch('input', quill.root.innerHTML);
});
```

Code sample 2 (JavaScript)

```js
quill.on('text-change', function () {
  let quillData = quill.root.innerHTML;
  let customEvent = new Event('input', {data:quillData});
  container.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Alpine.js `$dispatch` function uses `CustomEvent` instead of `Event` see it here https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/master/src/component.js#L355

So your vanilla JS sample needs to be:

```js
quill.on('text-change', function () {
  let quillData = quill.root.innerHTML;
  let customEvent = new CustomEvent('input', {detail:quillData});
  container.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Hugo! Trying to guess the key name for one day (tried data, etc) turn out its detail!

Comment: It's quite helpful for my next project. Helped me to learn what happens under the hood.